# Spring boot : Read external drools rule engine file

Tags: spring-boot, drools

I have a Spring boot application `(version 2.7.4)` and I am trying use drools rule engine in this application. Currently this application is working fine if I specify the file in class path under resources folder. I want to move this rule file outside of the jar and use that file at runtime.

I tried using `ResourceFactory.newFileResource(ruleFilePath)` but whenever Jenkins build process runs it fails saying file does not exist at the given path. Is there any way to move .drl file completely out of the code repository?

Comment: So, when you run it locally it does work but it is failing only in Jenkins? Are you sure the file exists in the Jenkins' file system? What is the value of `ruleFilePath`?

Comment: This deployment is in Kuberentes pods. Our CICD is pipeline is setup in a such way that the file will be there in the pod. I am trying Jenkins (build process) not to look for this file. Just the way secrets are injected into Spring application at runtime and not at the build time.

Comment: Why not just mount the volume containing the DRL resources onto the application classpath? The DRLs don't need to be part of the build, they just need to be on the classpath when you run the applicaiton.

Comment: Putting it in the classpath leads to application re-deployment whenever any rule changes.

Comment: That's ... very strange behavior that doesn't sound like it's related to drools at all. Maybe you should fix that.

Comment: Otherwise you can always go the kjar approach and have the application pull the rules from a maven repo.